# Aligning HTML5 form elements

Tags: css, html, forms, alignment

I am new to HTML5 so all the help I can get is appreciated.  I have three fields (First Name, Last Name and Birth Date) and I am trying to align them together.  I would like to align the fields together horizontally and vertically.

Here is my simple code so far:

```
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<body>
  <form>
    <label for="firstname">First Name:</label> <input name="firstname" type="text" size="50" autofocus><br>
    <label for="lastname"><br>Last Name:</label> <input type="text" name="lastname" size="50" autofocus><br>
    <label for="birthdate"><br>Birth Date:</label> <input type="date" name="bdate" size="50"><br> 
  <form> </body> </html>
```

Here is the CSS I have:

```
input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid #D4E2F1;
}

input[type=date] {
    border: 1px solid #D4E2F1;
}

input[type=color] {
    border: 1px solid #D4E2F1;
}
```

I would prefer not use tables as I am not trying to display tabular data.  I am looking for a efficient and correct way to do this.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.
AJ

Comment: remove the br tag and float them

Comment: you may have labels float left and inputs float right.

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). If the `for` attribute doesn't match the **`id`** of the associated input, it is useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<form class="user-form">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
        <input name="firstname" type="text" size="50" autofocus />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" size="50" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="birthdate">Birth Date:</label>
        <input type="date" name="bdate" size="50" />
    </div>
<form>
```

CSS:

```
.user-form { padding:20px; }

.user-form .field { padding: 4px; margin:1px; background: #eee; }

.user-form .field label { display:inline-block; width:120px; margin-left:5px; }

.user-form .field input { display:inline-block; }
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VuSX4/

Comment: nice sample ,how can apply this to jQuery-Mobile ? because of pre-defined elements .attributes .

Comment: You need to find the names of the css classes that control each element. for the above, you could add in `.ui-input-text {width:auto !important;}` and it should be aligned. http://jsfiddle.net/VuSX4/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this
HTML:

> <
>       div style="display:block; position:relative; width:100(or something)px; height:auto;       margin:0px auto 0px;"
>   >
>      Put your form markup in here
>      <
>       /div>

I looked all over for this answer and found the information at W3C Schools and a bit of trial and error
This validates at http://validator.w3.org/